# iPhone GameKit:  Clients detect other clients

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0, gamekit

I'm trying to set up a client-server architecture.  I have one GKSession configured as a server, and two others as clients.

When either client uses the sendData:toAllPeers:WithDataMode:error method, it sends it not only to the server but to the other client.

I guess I could use the display name to exclude clients, so client data only goes to the server, but I'm not quite following why this is happening.

My server explicitly accepts a connection, via acceptConnectionFromPeer:error:  But my client isn't accepting anything from anybody, it seems to be just silently finding the other client.

Should this be happening?  I understand in a peer-peer setup you'd want peers to just find others;  but in client-server, this seems a little weird.

Any clarification or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

While a client cannot explicitly connect to another client, but the method **sendData:toPeers:withDataMode:error:** should allows you to send data directly from one client to another given that you have the correct peerId.